# REST - GET - Passing secret value

Tags: api, rest, http

I am designing a REST API for getting a gift card balance. I choose GET HTTP verb to be used for it. But then I realized that I need to pass the PIN number of the gift card for which balance needs to be fetched.
I am a bit puzzled with the design.

I can think of two approaches:

1. Use HTTP GET and pass PIN as a custom HTTP header (X-GC-PIN). **URI**: /giftcards/{gift-card-number}.
   PIN is not a meta-data so I am reluctant to pass it as a HTTP header.
2. Use HTTP POST and pass PIN in the body. And **URI**: /giftcards/{gift-card-number}/balance.
   But since this is a fetch call I am reluctant to use POST.

How I should approach this design problem. Is any of the above is more suitable or is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to recognize is that the entire HTTP request has the same exposure risk; anybody that can read the [request-line](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.1.1) can also read all of the request headers, including the custom ones.

So we secure the request by making sure that the data is encrypted in transit (https).

The motivation for keeping secrets out of the target-uri is that we're worried about the places that the uri is copied (caches, browser history, access logs, etc).

---

The URI is semantically opaque, from the point of view of clients.  In other words, if we have a document about pin 12345, this is a perfectly acceptable request to fetch a copy of the document:

```
GET /4551f68c-a1db-4bbe-b449-5b99be483a08
```

One possibility is to use a hash of the pin, rather than the pin itself, as the URI parameter

```
GET /pin?sha256=5994471ABB01112AFCC18159F6CC74B4F511B99806DA59B3CAF5A9C173CACFC5
```

We don't have, as far as I know, form input controls that allow us to specify that an input value should be hashed when copying it into the URI.  [Code on demand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5581461/54734) can work, for clients with that capability, but that's not universal -- you may be limiting the number of general purpose clients that can interact with your resources.

An alternative for computing the hash value to do it, is to submit the pin to the server in a form, and let the server [redirect](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4) you to the correct document

```
GET /pin?raw=12345
```

```
301 Moved Permanently
Location: /pin?sha256=5994471ABB01112AFCC18159F6CC74B4F511B99806DA59B3CAF5A9C173CACFC5
```

Of course, that doesn't buy you anything, because we've leaked the secret into the URI again.  We do a little bit better with...

```
POST /pin
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

raw=12345
```

```
302 Found
Location: /pin?sha256=5994471ABB01112AFCC18159F6CC74B4F511B99806DA59B3CAF5A9C173CACFC5
```

It's not ideal (general purpose components aren't allowed to assume that `POST /pin` is safe), but you only need to use it in those situations where you don't know the hash value and can't compute it yourself.  Once the server has told you the location of the document, you can re-use that URI as long as you can remember it.

A minor modification of the response will allow you to save a round trip:

```
302 Found
Location: /pin?sha256=5994471ABB01112AFCC18159F6CC74B4F511B99806DA59B3CAF5A9C173CACFC5
Content-Location: /pin?sha256=5994471ABB01112AFCC18159F6CC74B4F511B99806DA59B3CAF5A9C173CACFC5
```

Content-Location informs general purpose clients that the message-body of this response is a representation of the the URI, and a smart client can therefore see that it is a representation of the resource you are redirecting them to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand that HTTP headers are also encrypted.                         
I cannot send a hashed PIN because I need to forward the PIN to some other API.

Answer (score 0):

It can be GET and POST too. If the client is running in a browser, then better to use POST, because it is not cached by default or disable cache with the proper header.